# Mongoose : access custom stored function in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created custom javascript function in mongodb.

```
db.system.js.save(
{
  _id : "generateSRID" ,
  value : function (zone_id, length){ var randomNum = (Math.pow(10,length).toString().slice(length-1) + Math.floor((Math.random()*Math.pow(10,length))+1).toString()).slice(-length); return 'SR'+zone_id+'-' + randomNum; }
});
```

I have mongoose schema ,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    type: {type: String, required: true},
    service: {type: String, required: true},
    object: {type: String, required: true},
    method: {type: String, required: true},
    log: {type:String, required: true},
    srid : {type: String}  <== need to generate while saving
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Logger', schema);
```

My question is that, how can i access custom function while saving schema?
Is it possible, if no - what is the alternative.

```
var data = {  
              "type" : "Info",
              "service" : "customerService",
              "object" : "customer.controller",
              "method" : "getCustomerByMSISDN",
              "log" : "INVOKE:getCustomerByMSISDN",
              "srid" : generateSRID(2,10) <== access mongodb fuction
           };

const logger = new Logger(data);

logger.save(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }    
    console.log("## Log created successfully ##");    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using pre-save of mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    type: {type: String, required: true},
    service: {type: String, required: true},
    object: {type: String, required: true},
    method: {type: String, required: true},
    log: {type:String, required: true},
    srid : {type: String  }  <== need to generate while saving
});

schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.srid= '1234';
  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Logger', schema);
```

Note: For update use pre-update

Comment: i cannot use mongodb function for creating srId?